# Slider input whit hour shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do an slider input with hours, my row only has hour, it hasn't date. my code works very well, but when the slider input appears,it has a different rank of hours. My hours is 6:30 am to 9:00 am, and the slider unput show a year and a different hour 2:25 to 3:56, but when I look the dataframe the slider input is filter good. I dont know why is showing a different time .

my database is something like this

```
 library(shiny)
 library(tidyverse)
 library(DT)
 library(lubridate)

 surgeon.lastname<-as.factor(c("pedro","pedro","juan","andres",
            "camilo","juan","andres","camilo","andres",
            "claudia",NA,"juan","juan","juan","claudia",
              "camilo"))
  specialty.name<-as.factor(c("gato","gato","gato","perro",
          "perro","perro","perro", "buho","buho","buho",
          "buho","tigre","tigre","tigre",NA,"tigre"))
  admissionList.simpleCheckHour<-c("08:56:20",NA,"07:25:15",NA,
         "08:56:45","08:18:13","10:38:26","03:52:38","12:41:55",
          "02:32:58",NA,"03:58:37","03:58:37","06:21:46",
           "06:21:46","08:56:20")
  simpleOriginDate<-c("01/03/2020","02/03/2020","03/03/2020",
       "04/03/2020","05/03/2020","06/03/2020","07/03/2020",
       "08/03/2020","09/03/2020","10/03/2020","11/03/2020",
        "12/03/2020","13/03/2020","14/03/2020","15/03/2020",
        "16/03/2020")

df1<-data.frame(surgeon.lastname,specialty.name,
       admissionList.simpleCheckHour, simpleOriginDate)
df1$admissionList.simpleCheckHour<hms::as_hms
                (df1$admissionList.simpleCheckHour)
df1$simpleOriginDate<-as.Date(df1$simpleOriginDate,
                                                 "%d/%m/%Y")
```

this is my UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2"),
    uiOutput("Rango"),
    uiOutput("RandeDatedI")
    
),
mainPanel(
    DTOutput("t1"),
    DTOutput("summary9")
)))
```

This is my server

```
 server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$SeleccioneEspecialidad2<-renderUI({
    choices <- na.omit(df1$specialty.name)
    selectInput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2", "Seleccione Especialidad",
                choices=choices, multiple = T, selected = TRUE )
})

BD9<-reactive({
    req(input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2)
    df1 %>%
        filter(specialty.name %in% input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2 ) %>%
        filter(admissionList.simpleCheckHour >= hms::hms(0, 30, 6), admissionList.simpleCheckHour <= hms::hms(0, 0, 9))
})

FechaI<-reactive({
    BD9.1<-BD9()
    unique(BD9()$simpleOriginDate)
})

output$RandeDatedI <-renderUI({
    req(FechaI())
    mymin <- min(FechaI(),na.rm=T)
    mymax <- max(FechaI(),na.rm=T)
    dateRangeInput('dateRangeI',
                   label = 'Seleccione un rango',
                   start = mymin, end = mymax,
                   min = mymin, max = mymax
    )
})
BD9.3<-reactive({
    req(input$dateRangeI, BD9())
    BD9.2<-BD9()
    BD9.2 %>%
        filter(simpleOriginDate >= input$dateRangeI[1] & simpleOriginDate <= input$dateRangeI[2])
})
hora<-reactive({
    BD9x<-BD9.3()
    unique(BD9.3()$admissionList.simpleCheckHour)
})
output$Rango<-renderUI({
    req(hora())
    #min = as.POSIXct("06:30",format = "%H:%M"),
    #max = as.POSIXct("07:59",format = "%H:%M"))
    minn=min(as.POSIXct(hora()))
    maxx=max(as.POSIXct(hora()))
    sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = minn, max=maxx,
                value=c(minn,maxx))
})
BD9.5<-reactive({
    req(input$Rango, BD9.3())  
    BD9.4<-BD9.3()
    BD9.4 %>%
        filter(admissionList.simpleCheckHour>= input$Rango[1]  &
                   admissionList.simpleCheckHour <= input$Rango[2]) 
})

BD96 <- reactive({
    req(BD9.5(),BD91())
    dfsub <- BD9.5() %>% count(specialty.name)
    df1 <- BD91() %>% count(specialty.name) %>% rename(den=n)
    df3 <- dplyr::left_join(dfsub, df1, by=c("specialty.name"),all=TRUE) %>% mutate(Porcentaje = (n/den)*100) %>% select(1,2,4)
    df3
})
output$t1 <- renderDT(datatable(BD9.3()))

output$summary9<-renderDT({
    datatable(BD9.5(), class = 'cell-border stripe', options = list(
        order = list(list(3, 'desc'))))
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: 1. Please include all the libraries that you are using. 2. It seems you are missing a bracket somewhere, the `server` code does not run. Can you check and correct that? 3. What is `df1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use POSIXct a date element is added to the values.

To *not* show that part on the slider use the `timeFormat` argument.

```
    sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = minn, max=maxx,
                value=c(minn,maxx), timeFormat = "%T")
```

Comment: it works in part, now only show the time, but is a different time. My rank time is since 6: 30 am to 9:00 am but the slider input shows since 2:25 to 3:56. Although I see the data base, and it is filter in the right time.

Comment: This might be a timezone issue, but default UTC will be used. Try setting the `timezone` argument to the appropriate timezone.

Comment: I dont know how do that! I am looking for everywhere in internet, but I dont found solution

Comment: `sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = minn, max=maxx,
                    value=c(minn,maxx), timeFormat = "%T", timezone="GMT)`                                I could finally do it. It was a simple thing. Thank you a lot. @norie

Comment: @ErikaC Is that working for you?

Comment: yes it worked for my.